# Position of a div is changing when screen resolutin is changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am beginner and I am learning HTML, CSS. I am trying to make a webpage. Almost everything is working fine but I am having a trouble with a element. I don't know how to describe the problem. I give some images. Please check it out.

**Image 01:**

[image]

**Image 02:**

[image]

Every is ok on small screens like the first image. But when I switch to 4k resolution with chrome dev tool it looks like the second image.

Image and texts is going up at 4k resolution. But I don't want that. I want image and texts stay like first image in any resolution screen.

My Code:

```js
var typed = new Typed('.strings', {
    strings: [
        'Web Developer',
        'Front-End Developer',
        'Back-End Developer',
        'Programmer'
    ],
    loop: true,
    typeSpeed: 60,
    backSpeed: 10,
});
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
.br {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.py {
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
}
.btn {
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid gold;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: gold;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.75rem 2.5rem;
}
i {
    font-size: 20px;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
}
/* --------------- Header --------------- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.cover {
    background-color: gold;
    height: 25vh;
}
.box {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -15vh;
}
.box > img {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.name {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.strings {
    color: gold;
}
.btn-box {
    margin: 5rem 0 3rem;
}
.icon-box {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.social-icon {
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
}
/* --------------- Experience --------------- */
#experience {
    background-color: #000;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
.experience-1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 3rem;
}
.experience-1 section {
    border: 3px solid gold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
.experience-1 section h1 {
    color: gold;
    margin: 1rem 0 0.5rem 0;
}
.experience-1 i {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: gold;
}
/* --------------- Works --------------- */
.work {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.work h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.work-image img {
    width: 100%;
}
/* --------------- Work With Me --------------- */
#wwm {
    background-color: gold;
    text-align: center;
}
#wwm h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
}
#wwm p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
}
#wwm a {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}
/* --------------- Footer --------------- */
footer {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 3rem 0;
    color: gold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .experience-1 {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 2rem;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    header .name {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .sub-name {
        font-size: 28px;
    }
    .work {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-gap: 3rem;
        border: 2px solid gold;
        padding: 3rem 0.5rem;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 450px) {
    header .name {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .sub-name {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .experience-1 {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/dabananda-mita-portfolio-02-favicon.png">
    <!-- Unicons Icon CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <!-- FontAwesome Icon CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Google font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Dabananda Mitra</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/responsive.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- --------------- Header --------------- -->
    <header>
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="container box">
            <img src="./images/dabananda-mitra.jpg" alt="dabananda-mitra">
            <h1 class="name">Hi, I'm DEBU</h1>
            <h1 class="sub-name">I'm a <span class="strings"></span></h1>
            <div class="btn-box">
                <a href="#" class="btn">DOWNLOAD CV</a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-box">
                <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                    <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- --------------- My Experience --------------- -->
    <div id="experience">
        <div class="container py">
            <h1 style="font-size: 40px; color: gold;">My Experience</h1>
            <p style="font-size: 25px; margin: 1.5rem 0 2.5rem 0;">Specialist in need. Generalist at heart.</p>
            <div class="experience-1">
                <section class="br">
                    <i class="uil uil-airplay"></i>
                    <h1>Front-end</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>HTML</li>
                        <li>CSS</li>
                        <li>JavaScript</li>
                        <li>Bootstrap</li>
                        <li>jQuery</li>
                        <li>React Js</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section class="br">
                    <i class="uil uil-server"></i>
                    <h1>Backend-end</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Node Js</li>
                        <li>MONGODB</li>
                        <li>MySql</li>
                        <li>Flusk</li>
                        <li>DGango</li>
                        <li>Laravel</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section class="br">
                    <i class="uil uil-arrow"></i>
                    <h1>Programming</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>C</li>
                        <li>C++/Cpp</li>
                        <li>Java</li>
                        <li>Python</li>
                        <li>JavaScript</li>
                        <li>GO</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section class="br">
                    <i class="uil uil-setting"></i>
                    <h1>Tools</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Visual Studio Code</li>
                        <li>Git</li>
                        <li>PyCharm</li>
                        <li>CLion</li>
                        <li>IntellijIDEA</li>
                        <li>WebStorm</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- --------------- Works --------------- -->
    <div id="works">
        <div class="container py">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 45px; color: gold;">My Works</h1>
            <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; margin: 1rem 0 5rem 0;">Here are few of my former clients</p>
            <div class="work" style="margin: 3rem 0">
                <section class="work-info">
                    <h1>CURABITUR TECH</h1>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;">Curabitur Tech is id eros nisl. Cras id bibendum dolor. Quisque ultrices posuere ante sit amet varius.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn"">VISIT WEBSITE</a>
                </section>
                <section class="work-image"><img src="./images/works/one.jpg" alt=""></section>
            </div>
            <div class="work" style="margin: 3rem 0">
                <section class="work-image"><img src="./images/works/two.jpg" alt=""></section>
                <section class="work-info">
                    <h1>CURABITUR TECH</h1>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;">Curabitur Tech is id eros nisl. Cras id bibendum dolor. Quisque ultrices posuere ante sit amet varius.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn"">VISIT WEBSITE</a>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="work" style="margin: 3rem 0">
                <section class="work-info">
                    <h1>CURABITUR TECH</h1>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;">Curabitur Tech is id eros nisl. Cras id bibendum dolor. Quisque ultrices posuere ante sit amet varius.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn"">VISIT WEBSITE</a>
                </section>
                <section class="work-image"><img src="./images/works/three.jpg" alt=""></section>
            </div>
            <div class="work" style="margin: 3rem 0">
                <section class="work-image"><img src="./images/works/four.jpg" alt=""></section>
                <section class="work-info">
                    <h1>CURABITUR TECH</h1>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;">Curabitur Tech is id eros nisl. Cras id bibendum dolor. Quisque ultrices posuere ante sit amet varius.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn"">VISIT WEBSITE</a>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="work" style="margin: 3rem 0 0 0">
                <section class="work-info">
                    <h1>CURABITUR TECH</h1>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;">Curabitur Tech is id eros nisl. Cras id bibendum dolor. Quisque ultrices posuere ante sit amet varius.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn"">VISIT WEBSITE</a>
                </section>
                <section class="work-image"><img src="./images/works/five.jpg" alt=""></section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- --------------- Work-With-Me --------------- -->
    <section id="wwm">
        <div class="container py">
            <h1>Wanna work with me?</h1>
            <p>I'm currently available for work.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">START NOW</a>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- --------------- Footer --------------- -->
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2021 | Dabananda Mitra</p>
    </footer>
    <!-- --------------- Typed.js --------------- -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>
    <script src="./plugins/typed.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using all of those `vh` units to position elements might be the cause of this. It's because `vh` values are relative to the height of the viewport.

I would start with changing the values `vh` for the .cover and .box elements to `rem` values and work from there.

A quick example:

```
.cover {
    background-color: gold;
    height: 10rem;
}
.box {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -5rem;
}
```

In this way it's still flexible and less depending on the viewport. Keep in mind that using rem is relative as well. It's depending on the font size of the root element (the root HTML element).

More information about the different CSS units: [W3Schools CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)